Save and Read File into cookie or localStorage in PyScript
I am trying to write file in PyScript. Writing and reading is OK, but if I refresh the page, all changes are resetted. Can I make PyScript save specific file into localStorage? Like, /home/pyodide/oauth.json.
Library which i tried to use requires file read/write should remembered.
from pyscript import document
from os import path, getcwd
print(getcwd())
if not path.exists("./oauth.json"): # always true
  with open("./oauth.json", "w", newline="\n", encoding="utf-8") as f: f.write("{}")
  print("Created new File")
else: print("Already exists") # never happens


You can access localStorage directly it's API. In particular getItem() and setItem():
<!-- index.html -->
<script type="module" src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.4.1/core.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.4.1/core.css">

<button py-click="add_item">Add Event</button>
<button py-click="clear_data">Clear</button>
<script type="py" src="demo.py">

# demo.py
from pyscript import window, display
import json
from datetime import datetime
ls = window.localStorage

def refresh_display():
    data = ls.getItem("data")
    display(f'The stored document contents is: "{data}"')

def add_item(evt):
    # Add a timestamp to the list of events
    if data := ls.getItem("data"):
        json_data = json.loads(data)
        json_data['events'].append(str(datetime.now()))
        ls.setItem("data", json.dumps(json_data))
        refresh_display()
    
def clear_data(*args):
    ls.setItem("data", '{"events": []}')
    refresh_display()

refresh_display()

